# How to fit 3 Pagefooters above Details (without spaces)?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, reporting

I have this `Crystal` report:   *Don't mind the foreign language :)*

[image: Bottom part of my report]

**Map:** (Below the selected section)

PageFooter A: Services + Description.

PageFooter B: Only Services.

PageFooter C: Only Description. (not optional)

PageFooter D: Signature (optional)

"Service" is optional too, I'll explain that later... (after the behavior)

### **Behavior**

Client must select:

Show "Service" or not `AND`
Show "Signature" or not.

---

**IF "Service" selected:** (trial nº 1)

Pagefooter B and C must appear. (Signature too)

*B supress method:*

```
if PageNumber > 1 then
  true
else //Page 1
  if {?ISSQN} = "supress" then
    true
  else //With services
    false
```

*C can't be supressed.*

```
     ...
```

*D supress method:*

```
if {?posSignature} = "top" then
  true
else
  if PageNumber > 1 then
    true
  else
    false
```

Result:
[image: Broken pagefooter]

Only half of `PageFooter C` appears.

---

**IF "Service" selected:** (trial nº2)

`Pagefooter A` must appear. (note: this pagefooter is nothing more than B + C)

In this case, I can delete the two pagefooters (B and C), will happen the same thing above (trial 1), The report won't alocate space for the Section D. AKA: Crytal report can't manage to have 2 footers.

Result:
[image: Large blank space]

`Pagefooter A` appear, but there is a large blank space relative to the size of the supressed Pagefooter B + C, and `Pagefooter D` consumes part of that space. (maybe because he came later)

### More Explanation:

There is 2 optional sections, (Service and Signature) and the required Description.

4 states:

```
+Service +Signature 
-Service +Signature 
+Service -Signature 
-Service -Signature
```

I tried to make 3 Report Footers, the behavior of trial 1 happen.

I also tried to make 4 report footers (with the 4 states), if the client don't choose 1 of the optional fields, a white space is left in the report (like the behavior of the trial 2)

Comment: Why do you have a separate Pagefooter A and a copy of it which is B + C ?

Comment: The page-footer section is designed to be printed after the details section.  You can configure the details section to `Print at Bottom of Page` and `Underlay Following Sections`, however.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the suppression logic that you are using for each of the page-footer sections.

Comment: @David, For testing purposes. B+C for Trial 1, A for Trial 2. Two diferente errors.

Comment: @craig The 3 report footers must be below the Details section. But 2 of those footers, can be supressed. The problem is that I can't manage to show the selected footers at the bottom of the page. `Or there is no space enough, or there is too much blank space.`

Comment: If it's not confidential, can you mail me the report so I can check it?

Comment: @David, I'ts not confidential, I can. But you won't be able to run (there is a lot of parameters).

Comment: I'm just interested about the settings of each section, i wont need to run it.

Comment: Ok, how can I send to you?

Comment: I got my e-mail address in my profile.

Comment: There is no PageFooter A in this version. I deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get working using UnderlaySection option.

Map:

```
+Serice +Description +Signature (false, false, true)

-Service +Description +Signature (true, false, true)

+Service +Description -Signature (false, true, true)

-Service +Description -Signature (true, true, true)
```

Thanks for helping... :D

---

Now, the two optional sections fit the space, finnally!

BUT only works manually, I don't know if need some special formula, here is mine:

```
if {?service} = "true" then //If supress services
   true //do underlay
else
   false
```

### PHEW, works via code!

```
        if (param["posSignature"] == "top") //Dictionary of params
        {//danfe is my report
            danfe.PageFooterDescription.SectionFormat.EnableUnderlaySection = true;
        }
        else
        {
            danfe.PageFooterDescription.SectionFormat.EnableUnderlaySection = false;
        }

            if (param["Service"] == "supress")
        {
            danfe.PageFooterService.SectionFormat.EnableUnderlaySection = true;
        }
        else
        {
            danfe.PageFooterService.SectionFormat.EnableUnderlaySection = false;
        }
```